# how to compare umask

Tags: linux, shell, unix, interactive

I am trying to compare the `umask` of an user. I am getting an error while doing the comparison. The code I am using is

```
val=`su - user -c "umask" | tail -2 | sed -n "/[0-9]/p"`
if [ $val -eq 744 ]
then

   echo "477 found."

fi
```

When I execute this I am geting an error like:

```
sh: ^[H: A test command parameter is not valid.
```

I've tried with `=` in the compare command, but it is still not working.

Please give any suggestions.

Regards.

---

`val` has been initialised as `0`.

I am running this as root, so no login is there.

I've also tried giving quotes.

Comment: What is in $val before the test? Try `echo "$val"`

Comment: Does `su` produce a password prompt which ends up being the value of `val`?

Comment: val was initialised to 0 before giving the command.i am runnig this script as root,so no password prompt

Comment: did you check (i.e. output) the value of $val before the test? what is in it? btw. what is the output of `umask`? for me, it is just the umask, so tail and sed wouldn't be needed ...

Comment: and what shell is it? a bash? umask is a built-in command so that has big implications as well

Comment: Can you give the output of `umask` on your machine/shell?  It works for me without the `tail` and `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

You should quote the variable name in your test expression:

```
if [ "$val" -eq 744 ]
```

See [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) for why.

Comment: did that too...but again got an error like :    sh: ^M^[[3g^M        ^[H        ^[H        ^[H        ^[H        ^[H        ^[H        ^[H        ^[H        ^[H^M02: Syntax error

Comment: Please see cdarke's comment regarding the output of 'umask' on your machine. I would expect a simple 4-character string like "0022", not the stream of control characters you seem to be getting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code executes well on my machine, the only solution I can suggest is to use a slightly different syntax, sometimes different bash version complain about one syntax and accept another one:

```
val=`su - user -c "umask" | tail -2 | sed -n "/[0-9]/p"`
if [[ $val -eq 477 ]] ; then
   echo "477 found."
fi
```

Have a look [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for the difference between `[ cond ]` and `[[ cond ]]`.

Comment: ... and the difference between `[ cond ]` and `(( cond ))`.